# PLSQL statement does not retrieves different character set (junk) number type store in database

Tags: oracle, plsql, character-encoding

Table:

```
dummy_table
-------------------
min_value   number(25,4);
code        varchar2(10;  -->primary key
```

SQL

```
select d.min_value from dummy_table d where d.code='XYZ';
```

OUTPUT

```
1000.0000
```

PL_SQL BLOCK

```
DECLARE

ar_min_value    NUMBER(25, 8);

BEGIN

 SELECT d.min_value into ar_min_value from dummy_table d where d.code='XYZ';

  dbms_output.put_line('ar_min_value :  ' || ar_min_value);
END;
```

OUTPUT

```
ORA-01722: invalid number
```

Please somebody tell why plain sql statement could easily display the output as 10000.0000 whereas plsql code returns 'ORA-01722: invalid number' when the data is available.

Is this any thing to do with the character-set, and why it displays 1000.0000 in SQL and not in PLSQL code. If it related to character-set then how to make select query in plsql block to display 1000.0000.

Comment: You will either have no output at all (if you haven't enabled the client to see it), or an exception if there is no (or too much) data, or the fixed text you're outputting plus either a value or nothing. You won't just see 'null'. I'm not sure what you mean about `chr`, or why that is relevant for a number value.

Comment: What do you mean by junk? A number value of `1000.0000` is very unlikely to create any trouble with character encoding.

Comment: What is `d.code`? How are you using `chr`? What are 'junk values'?